# Unix Domain Sockets: errno 111 Connection refused

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, sockets

RPi3, Raspian Jessie, Python 2.7.
Hello all, I am struggling trying to do an IPC using Unix Domain Sockets.  I had it working some months ago, but alas, I can't seem to put my hands on those images with working code.  My client is getting "errno 111: Connection refused" when it tries to connect to a socket created by another Python program.  I am currently using some demo code I found [here](http://www.velvetcache.org/2010/06/14/python-unix-sockets), and I believe it to be OK.  Here's the code:

Socket Creator:

```
import socket
import os, os.path
import time
if os.path.exists( "/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example" ):
  os.remove( "/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example" )
print "Opening socket..."
server = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
server.bind("/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example")

print "Listening..."
while True:
  datagram = server.recv( 1024 )
  if not datagram:
    break
  else:
    print "-" * 20
    print datagram
    if "DONE" == datagram:
      break
print "-" * 20
print "Shutting down..."
server.close()
os.remove( "/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example" )
print "Done"
```

Socket Connector:

```
import socket
import os, os.path
print "Connecting..."
if os.path.exists( "/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example" ):
  client = socket.socket( socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
  client.connect( "/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example" )
  print "Ready."
  print "Ctrl-C to quit."
  print "Sending 'DONE' shuts down the server and quits."
  while True:
    try:
      x = raw_input( "> " )
      if "" != x:
        print "SEND:", x
        client.send( x )
        if "DONE" == x:
          print "Shutting down."
          break
    except KeyboardInterrupt, k:
      print "Shutting down."
  client.close()
else:
  print "Couldn't Connect!"
print "Done"
```

ls -l of socket:

```
srwxr-xr-x 1 root root      0 May 19 14:26 python_unix_sockets_example
```

I'm thinking this is some stupid, simple thing, but I've been pounding my head against it for a couple days now.  Thanks for all help!

20160520@1413EDT update: Still fighting.  Changed from Unix Domain Sockets to regular IP sockets (socket.AF_INET), pointed both creator and client to "localhost", ran out of two separate terminal sessions on the same RPi3 and the client finally connects.  Now, let me try to work backwards to local domain sockets and see if a miracle will occur...Stay tuned.

Comment: Add the `ls -l` output of the socket to your question.

Comment: @ott, See my edit to the original post.

Comment: HI is it because when you use `bind()` you need to specify the `port` and the `host`? for Instance `server.bind((host, Port))` also I really also think that when using __UDP__ You need to use `bind()` at the client end too.

Comment: @Shan-Desai Yes, if I was using network sockets, bit this is a Unix Domain Socket.  Both sides of the socket exist on the same machine.  Is that right?

Comment: @AutoDoc Hi Can you do something like resuse the Socket. you can tell the socket to be resused if you are using __Loopback Address__.
`socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)` this makes the multiuse of socket.

Comment: Isn't the name `/tmp/python_unix_sockets_example` not somewhat different from `uds_socket`?

Comment: @Shan-Desai Perhaps that would work, but in the production logic I am working on, others have written js code to create a UDS so I must be able to connect to it in its native form.  I have no access to the UDS creator logic.

Comment: @ott, Sorry, I looked in a directory I was using for an earlier test.  I have edited the OP.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The mode should be rwxrwxrwx I think.

Comment: @AutoDoc I am still trying to connect dots with my network sockets logic. Also can you do something like not giving too much of binding constraints on the Server and Receiver by doing something like `socket.bind(('',port))`? Sorry since I haven't used UNIX sockets.

Comment: @ott, that's what I was thinking, but I'm running the logic out of idle which I fire up as "sudo idle", so I figure my logic should have root rights wherever I go.  Also, I expected to get a "permissions" error if it's a rights error and not a connection refusal.

Comment: @Shan-Desai, I may try that just to see what happens if I struggle here much longer.  Have you copied the logic in my OP and tried it on your hardware?  If so, what happened?

Comment: Make the mode 777 and handle the auth in an upper layer.

Comment: @ott, Tried it...No help.

Comment: How did youchange the mode?

Comment: @ott, I tried creating the socket in a directory that was 777, and still it had the permissions as listed in the OP.  The logic deletes any existing socket that it finds before re-creating so it's not like I can go into the OS and do a chmod as the "file" gets wiped out upon re-execution.  I have put an os.chmod line in my code right after the bind statement, but now that I look at the socket, it does not have 777 permissions.  Why this is, I don't know, but I fear I may be barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: @ott Update: I put in os.chmod making everyone RWX, ran the logic, and it still failed.  I looked at file permissions and they were s------rwx which I believe to be OK (but I'm not really a Unix guy, I just play one when the boss makes me.  I'm really a PLC programmer).  Can you take the logic and run it on any hardware you have to see what your results are?

Answer (score 1):

Finally:  The reason I was unable to connect both ends to the domain socket was because (for an unknown reason to me) I was running my logic out of Idle.  If I fired up two different terminal sessions; one with the creator, and the other with the client, all worked as expected.  There's three days of my life that I won't get back (unless I forget how I got things going and go back through this again).

Thanks to @ott and @Shan-Desai for your help.